# Problems integrating DynamoBD with API Gateway

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to use dynamoDb with API Gateway, but it is not working. This is what I'm trying to do

```
export async function handler(event: APIGatewayProxyEvent, context: Context): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> {
    switch (event.httpMethod) {
        case "GET":
            var params = {
                TableName: 'Users',
                Key: {
                    UserID: event.queryStringParameters.UserID
                }
            };

            dynamodb.get(params, function (err, data) {
                if (err){
                    return{
                        statusCode: 200,
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            message: "Item not found"
                        })
                    }
                } else {
                    return {
                        statusCode: 200,
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            message: data.Item,
                        })
                    };
                }
            })
            break;
    }
```

Every time I try to call my gateway I get a

```
{
    "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

Is it a problem with my integration ?

Another doubt, how can I add other routes to my Gateway ? I'm using CloudFloration Template and it's this:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'

Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Resources:
  UserAPI:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: build/userAPI.handler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        Api:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /users
            Method: ANY
```

How can I add a route like /user (GET) or /users (POST) ?

As requested I get the logs so the lambda is no been invoked the error I get is:

```
2021-06-23T12:08:37.557Z    eb945ca9-a4b6-4f8e-add1-774276db2cb7    ERROR   Invoke Error    {
    "errorType": "TypeError",
    "errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'UserID' of null",
    "stack": [
        "TypeError: Cannot read property 'UserID' of null",
        "    at Runtime.handler (/var/task/build/userAPI.js:12:57)",
        "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does the lambda produce any logs, if so: what logs? Add logging. If the lambda does not get invoked: is the api gateway permitted to invoke the lambda?

Comment: @luk2302 I added the logs, see if it ok now

Comment: Apparently `event.queryStringParameters` is not set.